# Pair RDD value filtering in Spark Python giving empty results

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have used the following code:

```
resultRDD = (
    data 
    .flatMap(lambda sentence:sentence.split(","))  
    .map(lambda word: word.split("\t"))  
    .map(lambda x: (x[6],(x[16],x[1])))
    .groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: list(x))

)
```

To create a pair rdd:

```
[(u'$SRVEU2-SV1-PKS',
[(u'14', u''),
 (u'14', u'OK'),
 (u'14', u''),
 (u'14', u''),....
```

I would like to filter by the second column in the list where value = OK.
I tried

```
resultRDD.filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'OK')
```

But this does not return any results.

Answer (score 0):

The value is a `list` so you should iterate over it:

```
resultRDD.filter(lambda x: any(y == "OK" for _, y in x[1]))
```

Comment: I tired your suggestion but I get an error -"ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: `resultRDD.filter(lambda x: any(y == "OK" for  y in x[1]))`